# jquery automatically check checkbox with values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a table like so

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>431</td>
      <td>Ana</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" class="checkboxes" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>tom</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" class="checkboxes" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a jquery array where there some ids stored of those rows example

`id= [123,431,213]`
what I want is when my page loads the ids which are inside the array to be already checked

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//code

});
```

I do not know how to go about this any help would be helpful

Comment: Why does your checkbox have a name, and why are there two brackets?!

Comment: How did your tr are defined??? Becuase first tr has header name and second tr has values. Is it correct?? Shouldn't these header be inside thead section?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Iterate over each row in the table body and for each take the text value of the first cell and check to see if your array includes it.

```js
const arr = [ 431, 123, 888 ];

// Iterate over the rows
$('tbody tr').each((i, el) => {
  
  // Grab the first cell's text and coerce it to a number
  const number = Number($(el).find('td').first().text());

  // If the value is in the array
  if (arr.includes(number)) {

    // Find the input and check it
    $(el).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>431</td>
      <td>Ana</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" class="checkboxes" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>124</td>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" class="checkboxes" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>tom</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" class="checkboxes" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the variable number for some reason is 0, it doesnt go inside the if, forgot to mention this is a server side datatable

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. The markup in my answer is your markup, and my code works fine with it.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var ids = ['431', '132'];
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('td.id').each(function( index ) {
       if (ids.includes($(this).text())){
          $( "input.checkboxes" ).eq( index ).prop( "checked", true );
         }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="id">431</td>
      <td>Ana</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" class="checkboxes" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="id">123</td>
      <td>tom</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" class="checkboxes" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```